# How to use decorator in my package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, decorator, wrapper

I want to use original decorator in my original package (ex.'with_error_handler' in 'mypackage') and execute some function.
But it returns function object or error massage that too given arguments.

In my package:

```
def with_error_handler(func):
    import traceback
    from functools import wraps
    from decorator import decorator
    @decorator
    @wraps(func)
    def error_handler(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            strError = traceback.format_exc() + __file__ + '(' + str(args) + str(kwargs) + ')'
            print(strError)
    return error_handler
```

And I want to execute below code.

```
import mypackage

@mypackage.with_error_handler
def divnum(num):
    print(1/num)

@mypackage.with_error_handler
def divone():
    print(1/1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    divnum(2)
    divone()
```

These result is here

```
>>>divnum(2)
･･･with_error_handler() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>>>divone()
･･･<function __main__.divone>
```

Why these error is occured?
How to fix it?

Comment: `print strError` is not coherent with the use of Python-3.x.

Comment: You are mixing up "out-of-the-box" creation of decorations and [decorator.decorator](http://decorator.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests.documentation.html#decorator-decorator) third-party library. They interfere with each other, just stick with one.

Comment: Also:
`if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: I'm sorry my code is incorrect. I will be careful it.

Comment: And I fixed it.

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do so. I remind you this because newcomers always forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `from decorator import decorator`. Doing

```
import functools as ft
import traceback

def with_error_handler(func):
    @ft.wraps(func)
    def error_handler(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            strError = traceback.format_exc() + __file__ + '(' + str(args) + str(kwargs) + ')'
            print(strError)
    return error_handler
```

is okay.

```
>>> divone()
1.0
>>> divnum(2)
0.5
```

and as expected

```
>>> divnum(0)
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/user/mypackage.py", line <X>, in error_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/mypackagetest.py", line <Y>, in divnum
    print(1/num)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero 
/home/user/mypackage.py((0,){})
```

Comment: Also:
`
>>>divnum(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/mypackage.py", line 8, in error_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/mypackagetest.py", line 5, in divnum
    print(1/num)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
/home/user/mypackage.py((0,){})
`

Comment: @bigmacd. Do you mean that showing how things go when an error is raised can be a good idea ? You are right.

Comment: @Kanak I realized that what I want to do. Thank you